# Convert bytes in a pandas dataframe column into hexadecimals

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

There is a problem when pandas reads `read_sql` bytes column.
If you look at the sql request through DBeaver, then the bytes column shows differently, but if you look at it through `read_sql`, it seems that pandas translates the value into a hex.

For example, pandas shows column value -

```
b'\x80\xbc\x10`K\xa8\x95\xd8\x11\xe5K\xf9\xe7\xd7\x8cq'
```

I need -

```
0x80BC10604BA895D811E54BF9E7D78C71
```

If I use, in sql,

```sql
CONVERT(varchar(max),guid,1)
```

pandas give correct values.
But I need to convert column in python not in sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the column (which I call `'col'` below) contains bytes. There's the `.hex()` method that you can map to each item in the column to convert them into hexadecimal strings.

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda e: e.hex())
```

This produces

```
80bc10604ba895d811e54bf9e7d78c71
```

It seems the specific output you want is to have the "0x" prefix and have upper-case letters for the digits above 9, which you can do by calling `.upper()` on the hex string and prepend '0x'.

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda e: '0x' + e.hex().upper())
```

This produces

```
0x80BC10604BA895D811E54BF9E7D78C71
```

Comment: I have one error if column value None - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hex'

Comment: @fikos Then try: `df['col'].map(lambda e: '0x' + e.hex().upper() if e else e)` which keeps None and modifies the bytes.

Comment: thanks  , i find different method df.fillna(bytes(0),inplace=True) .

Comment: i have one error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hex'

Comment: @fikos that means there are strings (not bytes) in the column. Without looking at what you exactly have, the easiest fix is probably `df['col'].apply(lambda x: x.encode().hex() if isinstance(x, str) else x.hex())` but I feel like you'll need to identify which rows are giving you problems first.